# Microsoft Blend 2017 how to import image file in .obj format

Tags: image, xaml, blend

Trying to import an .obj image file into Microsoft Blend 2017 so it can be used in a Viewport3D.  I can successfully import the .obj into the project, but can't seem to use it in a Viewport3D in a Window.

Some links I have found say to look for an "Insert" menu item after RH clicking on the .obj, but that menu item seems to be nowhere to be found.
Any ideas how to actually use the .obj image in the project would be helpful.

Screenshot of menu:
[image: Screenshot of menu]

Comment: What is the exact file format of this `.obj` file? Is it a raster image (e.g. a bitmap) or a 3D model or something else?

Comment: @Dai it is a text file in the .obj format and represents a 3d image-Sample data:   
mtllib imac.mtl
# r case
v 0.05576801 0.30063332 -0.04766447
v 0.05570779 0.30186484 -0.04785972
v 0.05553087 0.30306199 -0.04804953
v 0.05524284 0.30421927 -0.04823301
v 0.05484927 0.30533118 -0.04840930

Comment: Do you found a solution?